# SagePay & Magento. Tokenized payment

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, opayo

I'm developing a site which needs to utilize SagePay's token system within Magento.

The module I'm using to do this is Ebizmarts SagePay Suite http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-sage-pay-approved.html

Problem I'm having is it doesn't seem to be storing any token data in the sagepaysuite_tokencard database table. Even though I've selected the Token Integration - Server method. However, on checkout the option is there to save details for next time.

Could this be that my client's SagePay account does not have the ability to make tokenized payments? Or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cards are saved once the transaction completes.

I'd recommend you check whether the vendor has Token on both their Test and Live Sage Pay account. If they have do not have Token, ask them to call Sage Pay on 0845 111 4466.

If you are using Ebizmarts Community Edition (FREE) version of their module, the latest release can be downloaded [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-sage-pay-approved.html).

If you are using the PRO version (chargeable extension) please email Ebizmarts via info@ebizmarts.com as they have excellent support.